# NLTK wordnet calculating path similarity of words in two lists

Tags: python, error-handling, nltk, wordnet, traceback

I'm trying to find the similarity of words in a text file. I have attached the code below where i read from a text file and split the contents into two lists but now i would like to compare the words in list 1 to list 2.

```
file = open('M:\ThirdYear\CE314\Assignment2\sim_data\Assignment_Additional.txt', 'r')
word1 = []
word2 = []

split = [line.strip() for line in file]
count = 0

for line in split:
    if count == (len(split) - 1):
        break
    else:
        word1.append(line.split('\t')[0])
        word2.append(line.split('\t')[1])
        count = count + 1  

print(word1)
print(word2)

for x, y in zip(word1, word2):
    w1 = wordnet.synset(x + '.n.1')
    w2 = wordnet.synset(y + '.n.1')
    print(w1.path_similarity(w2))
```

I want to iterate through both lists and print their path_similarity but only when they abide to the rules wordnet.synset(x + '.n.1') meaning any words that do not have '.n.1' i want to ignore and skip but i'm not entirely sure how to make this  check in python

Comment: Could you show a couple of example input/output? How does the input file look like? What is the expected output?